# missing files in html

Tags: html, r, github, github-pages, bookdown

I use [bookdown](https://bookdown.org/) to generate HTML files for software documentation. The HTML looks fine locally, but once checked into the `gh_pages` branch, the figure links are broken.

For example, [this page](https://github.com/topepo/caret/blob/gh-pages/measuring-performance.html) links to [this image](https://github.com/topepo/caret/blob/gh-pages/_main_files/figure-html/perf_test_set_plot-1.png) via

```
<img src="_main_files/figure-html/perf_test_set_plot-1.png" width="672"/>
```

but [the link](http://topepo.github.io/caret/_main_files/figure-html/perf_test_set_plot-1.png)

```
http://topepo.github.io/caret/_main_files/figure-html/perf_test_set_plot-1.png
```

doesn't exist.

It doesn't seem to be an HTML issues since, locally, the files render fine.

Comment: GH Pages has some known issues with relative paths. Could you try putting a leading `/` on the path URL?

Comment: do you mean `src="/_main_files/figure-html/perf_test_set_plot-1.png"`?

Comment: It looks like the issue is the leading `_` in `_main_files`. Renaming everything `main_files` fixed the issue.

Comment: Cool. I've never had a problem with GH Pages, but doing some research it looks like people had trouble with capitalization and some other characters. Glad it got fixed